# How to setup node environment to run ES6 codes involving syntax like `import ... from ...`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, babeljs

I want to run the following codes based on [source code here](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/master/src/value.js) containing some ES6 syntax like `import ... from ...`:

```
import rgb from "./rgb";
import array from "./array";
import date from "./date";
import number from "./number";
import object from "./object";
import string from "./string";
import constant from "./constant";

var interpolateValue = function(a, b) {
// set var t and c
  var t = typeof b, c;

// if b is null or t is type boolean, 
  return b == null || t === "boolean" ? constant(b)
      : (t === "number" ? number
      : t === "string" ? ((c = color(b)) ? (b = c, rgb) : string)
      : b instanceof color ? rgb
      : b instanceof Date ? date
      : Array.isArray(b) ? array
      : isNaN(b) ? object
         // (a,b) is 2 function args
      : number)(a, b);
}

console.log(interpolateValue("foo", "bar")(0.5));
```

I tried to run this code inside a node project with `d3.js` as dependencies. However, I recieved the following error pointing at `import` in console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

**my question**:

1. How can I set up a node environment step by step in order to run codes with ES6 syntax?

---

2. with help of the first answer, I managed to set up the environment to run successfully (details can be found in the second solution), but the speed of compiling seems slow. Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: did you get it figured out?

Comment: yes, thanks. but I added a second question, but I am not sure whether it is appropriate to put them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need babel. Have you checked out the documentation here:
https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-core
```

then:

```
require("babel-core").transform("code", options);
```

after that make sure you've setup your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Kenny an important thing here is that for modern nodejs versions you don't need the complete `es2015` preset, it's an overkill.

Comment: @zerkms this is a good point. You're adding extra overhead where it really isn't needed!

Comment: thanks @zerkms, I will give a try later see whether this overkill cause the slow performance.

Comment: @zerkms, I tried to uninstall `babel-preset-es2015` but errors occurred `error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/Na...`. When you say "you don't need the complete `es2015` preset", do you mean I could uninstall `babel-preset-es2015` or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Kenny I meant - you don't need to install it at all. Not sure how you "installed" it, but usually all what you need to do is just to remove it from `package.json` and delete the whole `node_modules`.

Comment: @zerkms, if I understand you right, then I run my solution below again, I should not run the following code `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`, and the rest of codes remain the same, right?

Comment: I tried again to start from beginning using my solution below, installed everything and leaving `babel-preset-es2015` out, it won't work without it. by the way, I also updated to `node v4.4.7` and `npm 3.10.5`.

Comment: "it won't work without it. by the way" --- so what did you do for it to work? 1. nodejs v4 is too old 2. You still need a babel plugin that transforms `imports`: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/

Answer (score 0):

as @abigwonderful pointed out the babel site provided ways to setup environment to translate ES6 code to ES5. Below is the solution which I found comfortable to me at this moment.

1. create a directory and run `npm init` at its terminal;
2. move inside this directory's terminal run `npm install --save-dev PackageName` for the following packages: `browserify`, `babel-cli`, `babelify`, `babel-preset-es2015`;
3. run `npm install --save d3`;
4. run `echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc`;
5. by now, env is all set. when your `scritp.js` is ready, in the terminal run `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node script.js`

It seems quite slow, as `brackets` warned that there are over 30,000 files in the project, some of its features will be disabled. maybe for the similar reasons, this method above works but seems slow to me. Does anybody know why and how to solve it?

Thanks!